# How to correspond string to specific number and number to specific string

Tags: javascript

Lets say we have:

- `0`: `"APPLE"`
- `1`: `"ORANGE"`
- `2`: `"GRAPES"`
- ...

Is there a structure in JavaScript that allows me to get `"ORANGE"` from `1` and `1` from `"ORANGE"`? I remembered there was such a thing (not `Object` or `Array`) but can't remember its name, and I couldn't figure out a way to Google it without already knowing what it's called :(

Unless what I'm remembering is from ruby, not JS? In which case what do you call this?

## EDIT

I am aware that `Object` and `Array` can achieve the same result. At this point I just really want to know if there's a specific structure for it, and what its name is, because I thought I remembered seeing it somewhere, either in JS or ruby. Please tell me what it's called, or tell me it doesn't exist, so I can have an ease of mind again..

For JS, I don't think it is `Map` either, because the value -> key direction still needed a bit of work.

Comment: maybe you are looking for [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: You *can* easily do that with an object, though

Comment: @CertainPerformance Anyway getting key from value would require some loop, though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a two-way mapping in JavaScript, or some other way to swap out values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070836/how-can-i-create-a-two-way-mapping-in-javascript-or-some-other-way-to-swap-out)

Comment: @hindmost It's trivial though, and so would a `Map`, right?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Agree. But AFAIU the OP wants a _single_ structure providing two ways of mapping, which neither structure in JS meet

Comment: do you have a use case for this question?

Comment: @NinaScholz For unknown number of steps, I'm setting a `step_number:Number` to `step_name:String`, using the number value for conditions, string value for my own readability

Comment: for this, you could use just an object with number -> string and string -> number relations. for maps, you need the same or something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135661