# Is it possible to precisely type _.invert in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, lodash, typescript-generics, typescript-declarations

In lodash, the [`_.invert`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#invert) function inverts an object's keys and values:

```js
var object = { 'a': 'x', 'b': 'y', 'c': 'z' };

_.invert(object);
// => { 'x': 'a', 'y': 'b', 'z': 'c' }
```

The lodash typings [currently](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/21e68259f6fd43aba37e8112e3edb792975f8266/types/lodash/common/object.d.ts#L2001) declare this to always return a `string`→`string` mapping:

```js
_.invert(object);  // type is _.Dictionary<string>
```

But sometimes, especially if you're using a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), a more precise type would be appropriate:

```
const o = {
  a: 'x',
  b: 'y',
} as const;  // type is { readonly a: "x"; readonly b: "y"; }
_.invert(o);  // type is _.Dictionary<string>
              // but would ideally be { readonly x: "a", readonly y: "b" }
```

Is it possible to get the typings this precise? This declaration gets close:

```
declare function invert<
  K extends string | number | symbol,
  V extends string | number | symbol,
>(obj: Record<K, V>): {[k in V]: K};

invert(o);  // type is { x: "a" | "b"; y: "a" | "b"; }
```

The keys are right, but the values are the union of the input keys, i.e. you lose the specificity of the mapping. Is it possible to get this perfect?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Edit**

Since the introduction of the `as` clause in mapped types you can write this type as:

You can use a mapped type with an as clause:

```
type InvertResult<T extends Record<PropertyKey, PropertyKey>> = {
  [P in keyof T as T[P]]: P
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCMF4YG8BQMMwIYC4YHIAPfAGnUwCM98BPU1AX2whlEigG5VUoaAHAKYwAkmABuAgE5QASgIgBXADZQAPABUYAwlAFgAJizmhJ+1QAVJIQdJoBpATRIxL1qbwc0AfF8QpyANrmMACWYDAA1o4gAGYwmlgs6kEAuil45ozc+gLASliSQjEKYMBQIeCh4u6q5Bia2roGRrkgphZWNh6Ozq5d9o5eqF4AFCAUAFZ46gCUeKIS0nKKKhpeXKhKArAsSGGLUGMzHDBAA)

**Original answer**

You can do it using a more complicated mapped type that preserves the correct value:

```
const o = {
    a: 'x',
    b: 'y',
} as const;

type AllValues<T extends Record<PropertyKey, PropertyKey>> = {
    [P in keyof T]: { key: P, value: T[P] }
}[keyof T]
type InvertResult<T extends Record<PropertyKey, PropertyKey>> = {
    [P in AllValues<T>['value']]: Extract<AllValues<T>, { value: P }>['key']
}
declare function invert<
    T extends Record<PropertyKey, PropertyKey>
>(obj: T): InvertResult<T>;

let s = invert(o);  // type is { x: "a"; y: "b"; }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCMF4YG8BQMMwIYC4YHIAPfAGnUwCM98BPU1AX2whlEigG5VUoaAHAKYwAggBtRANSyiArgIgAeACowBhKALAATFgCUBoAE5aFABUMhBh3gGkBNEjHOWB1mnZoA+T4hTkMANqmMACWYDAA1vYgAGYwSgC6eMiR9nimjgBu0nJ4SkEJMAyMAVE0sfEJPPxCAJJgma5Q+hAyolDKquqaOjD6RibOVrb2jkNN7vbevmiYMEGh4WKSOfLKngH42bIC+AlJMACi6oZYwB3LUjuKSp6OKdu5TkUb+GV7jKhaBqJYhkIxGRgc4hcCLRrWBT+eJdDTaPQGEDGMwWYaTBxOVETDyeVCeAAUIAoACs8gBKPD1CHNeRtDq3LioUQCWAsJBhamEskcGBAA)

`AllValues` first creates a union that contains all `key`, `value` pairs (so for your example this will be `{ key: "a"; value: "x"; } | { key: "b"; value: "y"; }`). In the mapped type we then map over all `value` types in the union and for each `value` we extract the original `key` using `Extract`. This will work well as long as there are no duplicate values (if there are duplicate values we will get a union of the keys wehere the value appears)

Comment: Very clever! A union seems appropriate when there are duplicates since there's no guarantees about ordering. The only thing I don't like about this is that `InvertResult` always appears in the resulting type (on inspection, it shows up as `InvertResult<{a: 'x', b: 'y'}>` rather than `{ x: "a"; y: "b"; }`). But the type is correct and behaves nicely in all the cases that I tried and this may be unavoidable.

Comment: @danvk adding `{} & ` to `InvertResult` will expand the type in tooltips

Comment: Is there any downside to doing that?

Comment: @danvk it works well in my experience have not had any issues with it

Comment: If anyone cares, the most concise way I've found to do this is something like `type Invert<M extends Record<keyof M, keyof any>> = { [K in M[keyof M]]: { [P in keyof M]: M[P] extends K ? P : never }[keyof M] };`

Comment: How would i use this with _.invert() to get the correct types?

Comment: Playground link for the "Edit" answer no longer works.  Unclear what the issue is, and multiple errors.

Comment: @PeterH.Boling There was some text in the code in the answer that wasn't supposed to be there. But the link works fine for me

Answer (score 8):

The solution by Titian Cernicova-Dragomir is really cool. Today I found another alternative to swap object keys and values with Conditional Types:

```
type KeyFromValue<V, T extends Record<PropertyKey, PropertyKey>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: V extends T[K] ? K : never
}[keyof T];

type Invert<T extends Record<PropertyKey, PropertyKey>> = {
  [V in T[keyof T]]: KeyFromValue<V, T>
};
```

Test with `const o`:

```
const o = {
  a: "x",
  b: "y"
} as const;

// type Invert_o = {x: "a"; y: "b";}
type Invert_o = Invert<typeof o>;

// works
const t: Invert<typeof o> = { x: "a", y: "b" };
// Error: Type '"a1"' is not assignable to type '"a"'.
const t1: Invert<typeof o> = { x: "a1", y: "b" };
```

Declare the `invert` function in the same manner like above answer with Return type `Invert<T>`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-pAA1kAAoUCsAFZ0gCUKou6XBsTF43NzDwOHGygMF0jceeQA)

Comment: Very Clever!  Thanks for sharing @ford04!

Comment: To people with problem on non-PropertyKey values on this solution:

In case you have non-`PropertyKey` values, like `null`, or an object, in the main object (e.g. `const o = { a: "x", c: null }` where `null` cannot become a key of an object) all you need is to change `Record<PropertyKey, PropertyKey>` to `Record<Property, any>` in both utility function above and it fixes the issue by removing non-PropertyKeys.  Note that `KeyFromValue` will still work great and return the key. (e.g. `KeyFromValue<null, typeof o>` returns `"c"`)

Answer (score 6):

This becomes considerably simpler with TypeScript 4.1's support for [Key Remapping in Mapped Types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#key-remapping-mapped-types):

```
const o = {
    a: 'x',
    b: 'y',
} as const;

declare function invert<
    T extends Record<PropertyKey, PropertyKey>
>(obj: T): {
    [K in keyof T as T[K]]: K
};

let s = invert(o);  // type is { readonly x: "a"; readonly y: "b"; }
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20200929#code/MYewdgzgLgBCMF4YG8BQMMwIYC4YHIAPfAGnUwCM98BPU1AX2whlEigG5VUATAU2AAbLACc+MAGYBXMMCgBLcDHlgAbnxFQAPOQwAVGH0JQ+YHiwBKAkCJ5aACiJAAHDVBoBpPjRIxHLt09vAD5UYIAKEAoAKzw9AEo8NEwYAG0PZTAYAGtvEAkYAywWPXSAXTK8D0YuVEE+WBYkFXVNSPiODAB6Lph3V2UWZBgxLB5wQRoYQjwAIixZztHxsEmYGjmKRZgGVCA)

Comment: declare only defines a type which is erased after type checking, as such the function does not exist at runtime and makes the playground example not even run properly...

Comment: The interesting thing here is the types. The runtime implementation is trivial. You can either write it yourself or call lodash's [`_.invert`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#invert).

Comment: Simple and elegant. Just pay attention to the `as const` or you may waste more time than you're comfortable admitting.

Comment: Although this works, it seems to confuse the TS server type hinter - if you write s.x the type hint will be: ```(property) a: "a"``` -  maybe the ```as T[K}``` is at fault here because TS now converts the "x" to "a" for the hint output?
Either way, [Titian Cernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56416192/12473000)'s answer is more verbose but doesn't cause problems with the type hinting.

Comment: @notepadNinja `"a"` is the type of `s.x` there, though it is surprising that it says `a: "a"` and not `x: "a"`. Maybe file a TS bug?