# How to get the type of an interface property in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

So I have a code like:

```
interface MyInterface{
  a:any,
  b:string,
  c:boolean,
  d:number,
  readonly valueChanges:Subject<{key: keyof MyInterface, value: ???}>
}
```

where I dont know how to write the type of the value under the correct 'key'. I have tried the `typeof MyInterface[key]` but probably this is not how to solve it. :(

Thanks for your time in advance!

Comment: What is signature of `Subject`? Is it a function?

Comment: @PritamKadam I'm not sure why it matters. It's just a generic - might be a class or not. I don't see how it would change any answers.

Comment: It could be defined like this and types will be properly inferred:
`readonly valueChanges: <K extends keyof MyInterface>(k: K, v: MyInterface[K]) => void`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `AllValues` utility type posted by [Titian Cernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56416192/10431574). Note that you do not need the `extends Record<PropertyKey, PropertyKey>` as that is specific to the problem of inverting.

```
type AllValues<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: { key: P, value: T[P] }
}[keyof T]
```

You then apply this type to your interface, but make sure that `{key: valueChanges...}` isn't one of your options.

```
type KeyValueObject = AllValues<Omit<MyInterface, "valueChanges">>
```

```
interface MyInterface{
  a: any;
  b: string;
  c: boolean;
  d: number;
  readonly valueChanges: Subject<AllValues<Omit<MyInterface, "valueChanges">>>;
}
```

I don't like the circular referencing here, so personally I would break it into composable pieces.  `MyInterface` would end up as a `type` rather than an `interface`, but there is very little practical difference.

```
interface BaseInterface {
  a: any;
  b: string;
  c: boolean;
  d: number;
}

type WithValueChanges<T> = T & {
    readonly valueChanges: Subject<AllValues<T>>
}

type MyInterface = WithValueChanges<BaseInterface>
```