# How can I swap object key value and get valid return type of swap function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

When I swap object key value return type of function is { [x: string]: value } instedof const key.

Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHkBGArZBvAWAChlTkBtAawgE8AuZAZzClAHMBdB51kNgbmIBfQUWIIA9iGZMA7nAAOAMRDIAvMgA8AFWQQAHpBAATRmizYAfAAoJOBtoCU6y-mJlkk6WGRQIZjTwhZDgzPAoAaWRQZG0qWgkYWI4uZGoaRNjkEWJ3MgsIBDAAOghwVn9bHEdimAkoAFFEAAtra3iaABpkADc4ABsAVwgOZzVXQhIPMj9Gcj6hlFDYjsztFPU02lEPIUcdmYgwQahVWdEhXKIAemvfI5PVMBoFFEZmiUH+42RMCDpiLc3Dc7h44OCGAByOCQzqA0FkTBIqGYWHw7LRbwQH6ZSZAjzkfTcFjsVIAIjgZOQAB9kGTMGTREDLkQvDJZl8fBpGPJlCBrJMwVDwTC4VNSJgUUi0UQ9qIgA)

```js
interface IObj {
    [key: string]: string;
};

const swapFn = <T extends IObj>(obj: T) => {
    const res = {} as { [K in T[keyof T]]: keyof T };

    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        res[value as T[keyof T]] = key;
    });
    return res;
}

// return type should be:
// {
//     aaa: 'a',
//     bbb: 'b',
// } insted of {
//     [x: string]: "a" | "b";
// }
const result = swapFn({
    a: 'aaa',
    b: 'bbb',
});
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHkBGArZBvAWAChlTkBtAawgE8AuZAZzClAHMBdB51kNgbmIBfQUWIIA9iGZMA7nAAOAMRDIAvMgA8AFWQQAHpBAATRmizYAfAAoJOBtoCU6y-mJlkk6WGRQIZjTwhZDgzPAoAaWRQZG0qWgkYWI4uZGoaRNjkEWJ3MgsIBDAAOghwVn9bHEdimAkoAFFEAAtra3iaABpkADc4ABsAVwgOZzVXQhIPMj9Gcj6hlFDYjsztFPU02lEPIUcdmYgwQahVWdEhXKIAemvfI5PVMBoFFEZmiUH+42RMCDpiLc3Dc7h44OCGAByOCQzqA0FkTBIqGYWHw7LRbwQH6ZSZAjzkfTcFjsVIAIjgZOQAB9kGTMGTREDLkQvDJZl8fBpGPJlCBrJMwVDwTC4VNSJgUUi0UQ9qIgA)

Comment: The return type for `swapFn` states a contract that keys would be of type of values -- which are string in your case, and the values for each key would be a type of keys either "a" or "b".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to precisely type \_.invert in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56415826/is-it-possible-to-precisely-type-invert-in-typescript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two problems here.  The first is that your return type is too wide, since `keyof T` is the union of all the keys; each property will be `"a" | "b"` and not the particular `"a"` or `"b"` corresponding to the value.  This can be fixed by changing your mapped type, and can be done particularly easily via [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types) as introduced in TypeScript 4.1:

```
{ [K in keyof T as T[K]]: K }
```

We walk through each key `K` of `T`, and output `T[K]` (the property value type) as the key, and `K` as the property.  This swaps things.

---

The second problem is one of inference.  When you pass in `{ a: 'aaa', b: 'bbb'}` the compiler is very likely to infer that value as having type `{a: string, b: string}` because it is more common that people might want to change the value of a property to some other `string` instead of leaving it as some string literal.  There are different ways to convince the compiler to infer narrower types.  The easiest is for the caller to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
swapFn({ s: "t", u: "v" } as const);
```

But if you don't want callers to have to do that, you can use other tricks.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680) for a feature request asking for some less crazy tricks and some description of them.  I will add another generic type parameter `S extends string` that has no purpose other than to hint to the compiler that you want a string literal type.  Instead of `T extends IObj`, I will write `T extends Record<string, S>`.

---

Here's the full function:

```
const swapFn = <T extends Record<string, S>, S extends string>(obj: T) => {
    const res = {} as any; // I'm not worried about impl safety
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        res[value] = key;
    });
    return res as { [K in keyof T as T[K]]: K };
}
```

I changed around the type assertions; the compiler isn't really equipped to verify type safety of a "swap-keys-and-values" implementation so I'm not bothering to try, and using `any`.

Let's see if it works:

```
const result = swapFn({
    a: 'aaa',
    b: 'bbb',
});
/* const result: {
    aaa: "a";
    bbb: "b";
} */
console.log(result.aaa.toUpperCase()) // A
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBBDuBDADgMTDAvDAPAFRgFMAPKQsAEwhgCVDQAnCnaBgSzAHMAaGAZQB8vPkVLkqcKOy4CAFCABGAKwBcMPAEosAmAG8AsACgYJmKEiwGhatl0BfGImqIwATwDcMAPReYASQByAFsYMBBYeBAGdkIKRwUQAFdYNiDkABs4RAAzQihXI1MYAHlleigAOnIpNmt5ZQ0K7KiAUURgAAtZWQBtAGtCV14AN0R0xMIAXS1MHQNjItMrCB7R8amsGAGPQtM7DXddkysoRIYMZcdqXRgegGkYDi3BkGz1K-V7ycm1B7tDwx2IxGBAodCyG4QNQAIig0N4iRhw2hMAcTjM4GgB2BhnM0Bgy0S6Vg2FBaDAEKOjjUAUQdIC3CpChpClZDKM+wBXgAVBiLATrESoGp5kU6YgYYhoQCiqzmTBoQppRyYNyvEY8SB0oQKukQJxZITiRVxRUoCAAKrIZCEBgAYSchFkGi0PhgAEEgA)

Comment: what if object value is anouther object insted of string ?
`const result = swapFn({                                                                                                        
    a: { val: 'aaa' },
    b: { val: 'bbb' },
});`                                                                                                                                              is it possible to type it correctly, what do u think ? I edited playground

Comment: Sure, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/rNdQvm). Although that seems to be drifting away from the scope of the question as asked.

Answer (score 0):

In another way, you can strictly fix the types of key/val.

```
export const swapFn = <
  T extends string | number,
  S extends string | number
>(
  obj: Record<T, S>
) => {
  const res = {} as any;
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    res[value as any] = key;
  });
  return res as { [k in S]: T };
};
```

```
enum Sex {
  Male = 'male',
  Female = 'female',
}
type SexNum = 0 | 1;

const sexToNum: { [k in Sex]: SexNum } = {
  [Sex.Male]: 0,
  [Sex.Female]: 1,
};

const numToSex = swapFn<Sex, SexNum>(sexToNum);
const male = numToSex[0]; // this type is Sex, not string | number
const female = numToSex[1]; // this type is Sex, not string | number
```